# Specified member type is not supported linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone tell me what kind of error is this?

> The specified type member 'OrderDetails' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
>   What's wrong here in this code?

```
return storeDB.Albums.OrderByDescending(a=>a.OrderDetails.Count()).Take(count).ToList()‌​
```

Comment: can you post the code in controller and the view returned by the Action?.

Comment: In fact I have Resolve this thing by removing same line of code in my CartSummary.cshtml file thank you.

Comment: Sir I am now getting this Error "The specified type member 'OrderDetails' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." whats wrong here?      return storeDB.Albums.OrderByDescending(a=>a.OrderDetails.Count()).Take(count).ToList();

Comment: this is my OrderDetail class    class OrderDetail
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        
    }

Comment: The Order Details Is null as I debug it.

Comment: does your album has a virtual list of OrderDetails?

Comment: Are using EF code first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using EF code first try to add a configuration class to map the one to many relationship between Album and OrderDetails. The following will be a sample configuration for the Album.

```
public class AlbumConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Album>
    {
        public AlbumConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Id);
            HasMany(album => album.Orders).WithOptional(order => order.Album).
               HasForeignKey(order => order.AlbumId);
        }
    }
```

and your OrderDetails should be changed as follows

```
OrderDetail 
{ 
  public int OrderDetailId { get; set; } 
  public int OrderId { get; set; } 
  public int AlbumId { get; set; } 
  public int Quantity { get; set; } 
  public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } 
  public virtual Album Album { get; set; } 
  public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

and your Album class should have a virtual List of OrderDetails.

and finally in your DbContext class add the configuration by overrinding the OnModelCreating method. sample class would be

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
    {

       // your DBSets and contructors, etc


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AlbumConfiguration());            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }
```

Try this may be this is the cause of your exception

Comment: You will see a tick sign right next to the answer, which says "click to set this answer as the accepted answer", thanks

Comment: I am not seeing any tick,here is Answer You Question

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."Some body guide me how to retreive my account